# Numpy array filtering and modifying values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

To the following array

```
my_array = np.array([[11,12],[21,22],[31,32]])
```

I want to add 100 to the even values, so I write:

```
my_array[my_array % 2==0]+=100
print(my_array)
[[ 11 112]
 [ 21 122]
 [ 31 132]]
```

which is fine. Now if I write it with the plus symbol on the other side I get:

```
my_array[my_array % 2==0]=+100
print(my_array)
[[ 11 100]
 [ 21 100]
 [ 31 100]]
```

It seems to replace instead of adding the value, or to add the value to the result of the filter. Could somebody explain to me the reasons behind this and if this is the expected behaviour? Thanks !!!

Comment: Second step is simply assigning `+100` i.e. `100` to those masked places. What exactly is the confusion again?

Comment: I think OP is confused. `a+=b is same as a = a+b`. `a =+ b is nothing but a = (+b)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in `+=` and `=+`

`x += 1` is the same as `x = x + 1`

but `x =+1` is just saying `x = +1`, i.e you are assigning `x` to the value of positive one.

So it makes sense that in your second case you are assigning the value `100` instead of adding it.